# Is it possible to keep writing time stable when bytes are written at offset 0 on a file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems, ext4

linux kernel: 5.1.15
glibc: 2.29
g++ : 9.1.1
std: c++17
-Ofast
ext4fs
HDD: Seagate ST1000LM014 1TB SSHD 2.5"

```
std::array<int, 10000> state;
```

I write **nbrmsgs** ints from state to a file opened like so:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
persistfd=open("persist", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

with a call to:

```
pwrite(persistfd, state.data(), nbrmsgs*sizeof(int), 0)
```

This is all using synchronous writing. The requirement is to ensure data is written to file before continuing (ie if process crash after the write, data is in file, but if kernel-layer or hardware layer fails, that's not my problem)

Previously, I used **write** instead of pwrite, without specifying offset. This was therefore adding the bytes to the end of the file.

I was monitoring the elapsed time around the write, and it was fairly stable around 1 micro on my platform, up until the file reached a certain size and then the elapsed time starts growing, presumably because of all that's involved in relocating the inodes and all the tasks beneath the C library call).

I changed the write to pwrite, with offset 0, and the filesize does remain constant. However I still see elapsed time starting to grow after a number of pwrites.

1. Is it wrong for me to expect that elapsed time ought to remain stable now that the file doesn't not "grow" ?
2. Are there possible user level tweaks to ext4fs, or to kernel params to make it more likely that pwriting to 0 offset the same size of data, and with the file not growing, the observed elapsed time stays stable?

Comment: I'm currious; why is this important to you? The variance in time is going to be tiny - why does this matter? And if it really matters, maybe there's a better way to achieve what you want to do. So what is it that you *actually* want to accomplish?

Comment: The OS kernel is likely caching each of the writes. They are getting queued up to be written. OS likely isn't recognizing each is just overwriting the former. Once the queue gets large enough it starts waiting on the writes. You should look at the kernel source to see what it's doing.

Comment: How much was it growing? Without at least an order of magnitude, there's no way we can figure out what effect you're talking about.

Comment: BTW, it's also possible the disk itself is caching the writes and is the proximate cause. May not be in visible (unless you have Seagate source) code at all. In any case I don't view this behavior as unexpected. Quite the  contrary.

Comment: For the first 30 seconds, it's about 1/2 micro elapsed around the write.
Then it blows up to millis.
I'm afraid I don't know how to paste the measures here in this comment. I've pasted in a url that stack overflow forbids.
Here it is to be manually reconstructed. Apologies for this:
https    paste.ofcode.org     38hXMnTV54GWr6Mr4stUx8g

Comment: The size of the file as visible from ls remained the same throughout



`ll persist 
-rw-------. 1 xxxx xxxx 32768 Jul  7 22:12 persist`

Answer (score 2):

So you say you want it stable. No, you don't. You only think you want it stable.

To get it stable:

1) Get a dedicated SSD

2) Write your stuff with `write()`

3) `fflush()` before each measurement. This behaves better than `O_SYNC` in the case of the OS having to split a write due to memory pressure. Use of `O_DIRECT` will appear stable but really isn't.

There is no model in which stable times makes sense other than round-trip flush-to-disk. This is also the slowest model. Decide what you want.

Alternately if you don't care about crashes at all, use the oldschool RAM drives.

`# mknod -m 660 /dev/ram0 b 1 0` will make a dedicated ram disk in `ram0` you can scribble on thereafter. You still need to open with `O_DIRECT` for this to be stable.